# How to change the text of a TextView in an action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my Android application I have a TextView declared in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    [...]

    <item
        android:id="@+id/intro_button"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/intro_button"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help_button"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="@string/help_button"/>

    [...]

    <item
        android:id="@+id/user_id_label"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/session_info_label"/>
</menu>
```

At the start of an application, activity 1 is launched (it doesn't use the action bar). When it is completed, it starts activity 2, in which the action bar is displayed.

At the start of the activity 2 I need to set the text of the view `@+id/user_id_label` to a certain value.

I tried to do it in `Activity2.onCreate` and in `Activity2.onCreateOptionsMenu`, but in both these methods `findViewById(R.id.user_id_label)` returns `null`.

How (using which method) can I retrieve the reference to `@+id/user_id_label` text view?

**Update 1 (28.04.2013 20:25):**

I tried this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu aMenu) {
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, aMenu);

    this.menu = aMenu;

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu aMenu) {
    final MenuItem menuItem = this.menu.findItem(R.id.user_id_label);                               
    menuItem.setTitle(getString(R.string.user_id_text,
            getIntent().getIntExtra(ConnectToServerActivity.USER_ID, -1)));
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(aMenu);
}
```

But the label is still not shown.

**Update 2 (28.04.2013 21:05):**

This one works (in method `onPrepareOptionsMenu`):

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) menuItem.getActionView();

textView.setText(...);
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, I tried your update 2, but I only got null textView, anything missed for me?

Comment: I am having the same null TextView than @fifth, I suspect that this works when the item is actually 'shownAsAction', but not when it is hidden inside the overflow menu. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a reference to your `OptionsMenu` in a field variable:

```
Menu mMenu;

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        [...]

        this.mMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
MenuItem myMenuItem = mMenu.findItem(R.id.user_id_label);
myMenuItem.setTitle("New title!");
```